# Determining an Arbitrary Range of Digits in a Target Base from a Sequence and Source Base

Tags: math, function, floating-point, sequence

If I have a function *f* that computes element *m* of a sequence of digits in base *b*, is it in general possible to write a function *g* that computes element *n* of the corresponding sequence in base *c* ?

As a contrived example, say *f* produces binary and *g* produces hexadecimal:

```
f(m) → 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...
g(n) → A, A, ...
```

Now say *f* is in base 5 and *g* is in base 6. The bases don't share a common factor, which means that the number of digits required to represent a number from the source base in the target base is fractional (<sup>6</sup>⁄<sub>5</sub>). Is it possible to determine a single digit from *g* using only, say, the corresponding <sup>*c*</sup>⁄<sub>*b*</sub> digits from *f* ?

Note that starting the formula at the first element is the same as performing the standard conversion of a fractional number from *b* to *c*, but I want an arbitrary element of the target sequence, in the same way that I can retrieve an arbitrary element of the source.

Comment: Can you provide another example?  For instance, if `f` in base 6 is `f(m) -> 5, 1, 3, 2`, is `g` in base 3 `g(n) -> 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2`?  I can't really imagine what the desired behavior here is.

Comment: For base 6 to base 3, each digit of `f` produces two digits of `g`, so `g(n) -> 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 2`.

Comment: Sorry, my example was too simplistic.  How about `g(n)` in base 4?  I can't figure out if you want `3, 2` or `3, 3` for the first two results.

Comment: `g(n) -> 3, 2, ...` for the same `f(m)`. This is like the standard formula for base conversion, but I want to be able to retrieve an arbitrary digit of `g`, and I'm wondering if that's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any easier way than successively dividing by the base and keeping the remainder. Of course  dividing number represented in an arbitrary base would require a linear amount of work as well.

Lets say that f represents the number N then basically

```
g(1) = N % c;
g(2) = (N / c) % c;
....
....
....
```

It may not be necessary to to compute N explicitly, you could just do it implicitly in the base b.

Comment: So the answer, as I suspected, is "not exactly".